# Passar dois parâmetros para uma função que aceite somente um parâmetro

Tags: java, operadores, parâmetros

Estive fazendo um código para gerar um `pdf` a partir do *framework* `Itext` em Java. Me deparei com a seguinte situação, precisava eu definir uma frase como `negrito` e `sublinhado`. Após procurar no Google, encontrei a sugestão de um usuário para utilizar o operador lógico `ou` "|" de curto `circuito`. Porque essa função no parâmetro que aceita valores inteiro, só tinha apenas uma entrada.

Então o código ficou assim.

```
FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.defaultEncoding, 10, com.lowagie.text.Font.BOLD | com.lowagie.text.Font.UNDERLINE)
```

Sendo que essa função getFont neste somente aceitaria três parametros, e no terceiro parametro passei 2 usando o "ou" curto circuito, então gostaria de entender qual o intuito e porque a linguagem aceitou.

`com.lowagie.text.Font.BOLD` e `com.lowagie.text.Font.UNDERLINE` são um enum e respectivamente tem os valores `1` e `4`.

Answer (score 9):

Isso que vocêencontrou é um [bitfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) e é uma  maneira comum de se representar conjuntos de parâmetros booleanos de forma compacta.

A forma como funciona é que cada bit (isso é, potência de dois) do valor representa uma categoria de formatação diferente. Por exemplo:

```
NEGRITO    = 1 (decimal) = 0001 (binário)
ITALICO    = 2 (decimal) = 0010 (binário)
SUBLINHADO = 4 (decimal) = 0100 (binário)
```

Cada número então representa um conjunto diferente, dependendo de quais bits são 1:

```
6 (decimal) = 0110 (binário) = SUBLINHADO e ITALICO
3 (decimal) = 0011 (binário) = ITALICO e NEGRITO
0 (decimal) = 0000 (binário) = nenhuma formatação
```

O operador `|` é o operador de "ou binário". Para cada bit, o bit da resposta vai ser 1 se o bit for 1 em pelo menos um dos operandos e 0 se for 0 em ambos. No seu caso em que os números representam conjuntos de formatações, o `|` age como o operador de união de conjuntos:

```
0100 | 001 = 0101  -- SUBLINHADO | NEGRITO = (SUBLINHADO e NEGRITO)
0110 | 010 = 0110  -- (SUBLINHADO e ITALICO) | ITALICO = (SUBLINHADO e ITALICO)
```

Answer (score 6):

Não está passando dois parâmetros. Não há como passar mais parâmetros do que o método aceita. Você está fazendo uma expressão matemática com dois operandos e passando o resultado como parâmetro. Veja desta forma:

```
FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.defaultEncoding, 10, bold + underline)
```

Isto não é a mesma coisa, mas mostra com aritmética exatamente a mesma forma que você usou no seu exemplo. Vamos considerar que a variável `bold` valha, 1 e a `underline` valha 2, então você estará passando 3 para o terceiro parâmetros deste método, só isto.

Você provavelmente acabou de conhecer o operador lógico `|` chamado de "[OU lógico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective)" descrita na [álgebra booleana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).

Esta é uma forma simples de manipular *bits*. Você consegue ligar todos os *bits* necessários em uma operação. O parâmetros esperado é um *byte* ou sequência de *bytes* que representam vários estados lógicos. Cada estado é um único *bit* que obviamente pode estar ligado ou desligado. Se você pesquisar esta enumeração `com.lowagie.text.Font` verá que seus valores são exponenciais (0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16). E o OU lógico está apenas dizendo para ligar estes valores. No fundo é uma soma. Se, por exemplo, o `BOLD vale 2 e o` UNDERLINE` vale 4, o OU lógico garantirá que estes *bits* estejam ligados, resultando em 6.

Não vou me estender nestes detalhes do cálculo, isto a resposta do hugomg já explica e o AP postou um link em comentário ([Using Bit Flags and EnumSets in Java](https://eddmann.com/posts/using-bit-flags-and-enumsets-in-java/)). O importante para sua pergunta é que o operador `|` não faz aceitar mais de um parâmetro (na verdade o nome correto é argumento já que você está passando, parâmetro é o que recebe), ele apenas está fazendo um cálculo antes de enviar. Outra forma de ver:

```
int config = com.lowagie.text.Font.BOLD | com.lowagie.text.Font.UNDERLINE;
FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.defaultEncoding, 10, config);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Operator/BitFlag.java).

Fica claro que só tem três parâmetros.

Você pode ler mais sobre o operador [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34295/101).

Comment: Uma duvida que ficou, seria a seguinte, isso é feito pela `JMV`, pois estou imaginando isso a nível de `debug` entende, como isso que aparece no console por exemplo do `Eclipse`, seria mostrado os dois `enuns`, ou mostraria o `enum` desta soma.

Comment: Se você está falando do resultado final, não tem como mostrar os dois `enums` mais. Lembre-se do primeiro exemplo que eu dei. Se fosse uma soma, mostraria "bold + underline"? Não, mostraria o resultado desta conta. Com o `enum` vai acontecer o mesmo. Estes dois `enums` são constantes com um determinado valor. Não são construções mágicas da linguagem. Após você executar alguma matemática neles, só sobra o resultado. O outro lado, ou seja o método que está recebendo este resultado, deve saber como manipular esta informação.

Comment: Para complementar estou postando este blog http://eddmann.com/posts/using-bit-flags-and-enumsets-in-java/