# Operador " | " em Java

Tags: java, operadores

Não consigo encontrar nenhum material pela internet explicando a utilidade do operador "|" em Java.

Eu sei que existe o "||" (ou) usado para testar condições.

```
if(foo == 'a' || foo == 'b')
```

Mas e quanto ao operador " | "? Qual a utilidade dele?

Minha dúvida surgiu após encontrar o seguinte trecho de código:

```
int foo = START|MIDDLE|END;
```

Comment: Poderá encontram bom material na especificação Java.

Comment: @Renang tem como postar mais detalhes do caso prático? São strings mesmo as constantes? O | tambem pode ser usado em regex, seria legal se você contextualizasse melhor, pois dei uma resposta mais generalizada. Em outras palavras, se for exatamente da forma que você pôs no exemplo, teoricamente não tem como  funcionar. Talvez num caso extremo, se fosse um número no lugar do _bar_, mas mesmo assim está um pouco estranho o exemplo.

Comment: De fato, de acordo com a especificação o OU binário só se aplica a inteiros (ou tipos que podem ser implicitamente convertidos para inteiros) ou booleans (caso em que ele se comporta tal qual o OU lógico). O uso com strings deve produzir um `error: bad operand types for binary operator '|'`.

Comment: Eu ia dizer que é fácil encontrar material, mas o [material oficial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) realmente é bem lacônico. Boa pergunta.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

O Operador `||` é o operador "ou" para operações lógicas ("booleanas" ou "bulianas"):

```
if(foo == 'a' || foo == 'b')
```

É o mesmo que dizer `foo = a` ou `foo = b`, ou seja, qualquer um dos resultados sendo verdadeiro, a condição é satisfeita.

Já o operador `|` é o "OU binário", ele mescla os *bits* dos parâmetros desta forma:

```
0 | 0 = 0 
0 | 1 = 1 
1 | 0 = 1 
1 | 1 = 1
```

A lógica é a mesma do `||` (qualquer dos lados sendo verdadeiro, resulta em verdadeiro), mas se aplica aos bits individuais de cada um dos parâmetros. Como exemplo, `3 | 5` resulta em `7`, pois `3` é `0011` em binário, e `5` é `0101`:

```
  0011
| 0101
= 0111
```

Notar que neste caso, a operação realizada deixa um resultado numérico, pois estamos trabalhando com os valores, e não com um mero verdadeiro ou falso "generalizado", como no caso do `||`.

Normalmente as *flags* de um programa costumam ser definidas como constantes assim:

```
#define FLAG1 0x0001 // equivale a 0001 em binário
#define FLAG2 0x0002 // equivale a 0010 em binário
#define FLAG3 0x0004 // equivale a 0100 em binário
#define FLAG3 0x0008 // equivale a 1000 em binário
```

para justamente quando você fizer um `( FLAG1 | FLAG3 )` ter um resultado sem ambiguidades:

`FLAG1 | FLAG3` resulta em `5` no exemplo dado, nenhuma outra combinação dá isso.

Comment: Apesar dele entender já o significado/utilidade do `||`, valeu pela contextualização.

Comment: Seria bom colocar exemplos em Java já que a questão é de java.

Comment: @heat Eu concordo com o ponto de vista, até já tinha pensado nisso. Na verdade só não fiz no momento da resposta, pois queria atender o autor, que provavelmente esperava uma resposta, e usei a experiência no que eu uso no dia a dia. Apesar de não mudar muita coisa na idéia (até por isso basicamente ser uma troca de aspas num caso, e trocar os #defines), acho válido. Como provavelmente depois vou dar uma melhorada na resposta, é bem provável que eu aproveite e faça a adequação do código. Grato pelo feedback.

Answer (score 6):

O operador `|` é o "bitwise OR". Ele efetua a operação OR bit-a-bit e como o próprio nome indica serve para efetuar operações nos bits que compõem variáveis inteiras.