# Qual a diferença e para que servem os operadores & e && e | e || em Java?

Tags: java, operadores

Estava analisando algumas possibilidades para a implementação de um algoritmo e fui pesquisar esse tal de `&` e `|`, e li alguns tópicos em inglês mas não ficou 100% claro para mim para que ele serve e onde posso utilizá-lo. Então gostaria de uma explicação, mais clara e com exemplos práticos de como utilizá-lo. (E em minha língua nativa, no caso: **Português**).

**Perguntas**

- Qual a diferença entre os operadores `&` e `&&`?
- Para que serve o operador `&`?
- Um exemplo de uso para o operador `&`?
- Qual a diferença entre  os operadores `|` e `||`?
- Para que serve o operador `|`?
- Um exemplo de uso para o operador `|`?

Comment: Talvez aqui vai existir uma resposta completa sobre os 4 operadores, mas por ora, [esta aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34295/4337) responde bem sobre o uso de `|` e `||`.

Comment: A versão "dupla" seria para manipular valores inteiros, a versão "única" para lógica bit a bit.

Comment: Dica: Faz o curse de JavaScript do CodeCademy que tu pega isso rapidinho (:

Comment: @bpinhosilva nem sempre, veja minha resposta :)

Comment: Certo, @Math, mas o que quis dizer é que o operador & faz a execução lógica nos bits do operando ao contrário do && que o faz no valor verdade dos operandos.

Comment: @bpinhosilva o `&` também pode fazer a comparação no valor verdade dos operandos, dizer que o `&` **apenas** faz a lógica no bit a bit está errado.

Comment: @Math, talvez a minha expressão não tenha sido completa, há a diferença que você citou na sua resposta e ficou bem explicado. Eu disse que é mais utilizado para operação bit a bit, não quis dizer que seria "apenas" para isso.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A diferença entre os operadores lógicos que usam um símbolo e dois símbolos é que quando se usa dois é o que se conhece por **operadores lógicos de curto circuito**.

O operador lógico de curto circuito executa o mínimo de código possível afim de processar a operação lógica, ou seja, se você estiver fazendo uma comparação do tipo `if(false && true)` ao processar esse trecho e descobrir que logo o primeiro resultado é falso ele nem chega a analisar a segunda parte da lógica, então tanto faz se a segunda parte é `true` ou `false`, pois `false && qualquerCoisa` sempre dá `false`.

No geral, sempre se usa os comparadores lógicos de curto circuito, pois eles nunca serão mais lentos que os operadores lógicos de não-curto circuito. Entretanto é necessário ficar atento a situações excepcionais onde a execução ou não do restante dos operadores pode alterar o fluxo do programa e gerar um resultado não esperado, como por exemplo:

```
int a = 5;
if(++a > 5 || ++a > 6) a++; 
System.out.println(a);       //a==7
```

Contra:

```
int b = 5;
if(++b > 5 | ++b > 6) b++; 
System.out.println(b);       //b==8
```

[**Exemplo no Ideone**](https://ideone.com/GRSq0s)

No primeiro caso, por ser um curto circuito ele faz o primeiro `++a`, verifica que é maior que 5 e não continua a executar o código depois do `||`, pois `true OU qualquerCoisa` é `true`. Como deu `if(true)` ele entra no `if` e faz `a++`, tornando-o `7`.

No segundo caso, por não estar utilizando operadores de curto circuito ele processa tudo que está dentro do `if`, logo ele faz `++b` duas vezes, resultando em `if(true|true)` que é a mesma coisa que `if(true)`, ele entra no código dentro do if e faz `b++` tornando-o `8`.

Comment: Apesar da [resposta do Tiago Porsch](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61300/2998), ser bastante clara e explicativa, ele não citava esse comportamento dos operadores binários em `ifs` de `booleans`, como os operadores lógicos (`&&` e `||`), que era uma das minhas principais duvidas ao postar a pergunta. Então esse seria a unica diferença de utilizar um ou outro em uma condicional `if` de `booleans` (Entenda "`if` de `booleans`" como por exemplo: `if(valor1 > valor2 & valor3 < valor4)` e/ou `if(valor1 > valor2 && valor3 < valor4)`)?

Comment: Sim, a única diferença é o caminho menor a ser seguido quando se usa operadores de curto circuito. Eu foquei nas operações boleanas pois primeiro que o Porsch não citou, e depois porque ao perguntar a diferenças de `&` e `&&` eu levei a crer que apesar da operação binária ser interessante não era o foco, pois o `&&` nunca serve para esse propósito.

Comment: Perfeito Math, talvez também seja pelo fato de não ter especificado isso na pergunta, mas nem tem problema, pois assim as respostas ficam mais completas, e abrangentes. E além disso tem algumas coisas ali que também nem conhecia (a respeito das operações binárias).

Comment: Sim, claro, não tinha como você especificar algo que você desconhecia, rs.. De qualquer forma as duas respostas cobrem por total os operadores que você citou, e isso é bom, na minha opinião.

Answer (score 19):

**&** é uma operação binária, veja mais em [Wikipedia - Lógica binária](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_bin%C3%A1ria), Exemplo:

```
int a = 60; // Em binário, 60 é 0011 1100
int b = 13; // Em binário, 13 é 0000 1101
int c = a & b; // Complicado, mas quando os dois dígitos forem 1, o resultado será 1, se não será 0. Ou seja, "c" dará 0000 1100, que é 12.
```

**&&** significa "and", ou "e", por exemplo:

```
if (1 == 1 && 6 > 9) {
    // Se 1 for igual a 1 E 6 for maior que 9, isso vai acontecer, no caso não, pois 6 não é maior que 9.
}
```

**|** é outra operação binária, onde se algum dos dígitos binários forem 1, o resultado será um, exemplo:

```
int a = 60; // Em binário, 60 é 0011 1100
int b = 13; // Em binário, 13 é 0000 1101
int c = a | b; // Quando um dos dígitos forem 1, o resultado será 1 também. "c" dará 0011 1101, que é 61.
```

**||** significa "or", ou "ou", por exemplo:

```
if (1 == 1 || 6 > 9) {
    // Se 1 for igual a 1 OU 6 for maior que 9, isso vai acontecer, no caso sim, pois 1 é igual a 1, e isso já basta para o |.
}
```