# Trabalhando com Hexadecimais em Java

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, operadores, int, hexadecimal

Vi um exemplo de código no site de documentação do Java sobre bit que pode ser conferido [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Essa classe pertence ao exemplo que esta citado no *link* acima:

```
class BitDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int bitmask = 0x000F;
        int val = 0x2222;
        // prints "2"
        System.out.println(val & bitmask);
    }
}
```

Minha duvida é sobre como é possível que o valor imprimido seja igual a dois?
Como se da essa operação?

Peguei uma calculadora e vi que 2222 em hexadecimal corresponde a 8738 e
que F em hexadecimal é igual a 15 em decimal.

Com base nisto, como a expressão `val & bitmask` resulta em 2?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 7):

Primeiro: hexadecimal é só uma representação numérica, então pouco importa como ele foi descrito no código, o que importa é o número em si.

Segundo: não tem segredo algum se é sabido o que o operador `&` faz. Ele analisa bit a bit dos números e cada um deles resulta em 1 se ambos os bits coincidentes valem 1. E resultam em 0 em qualquer outra situação.

Então a análise é melhor feita em representação binária e não hexadecimal, decimal ou outra representação. Afinal o computador só entende o binário mesmo. As outras representações servem para facilitar para humanos.

Então

```
0010 0010 0010 0010‬
&
0000 0000 0000 1111
-------------------
0000 0000 0000 0010
                 ^
Só aqui coincidiu de ambos serem 1.
```

Relacionado:

- [Qual a diferença entre os operadores & e &&?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/101)
- [Operador " | " em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34292/101)
- [Para que servem os operadores | & << >>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52949/101)
- [Como ligar um bit em um número?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175345/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).