# Gerar números pares e ímpares aleatórios, com quantidades definidas

Tags: java, array, random

Como gerar números aleatórios com `Random` e limitando a quantidade de pares e ímpares?

Exemplo: devem ser gerado 50 números no total, sendo 20 pares e 30 ímpares.

```
public int GeraVetorParImpar() {
    contPar = 0;
    contImpar = 0;
    int x = 0;

    while (contPar <= 5 | contImpar <= 5) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
            x = (random.nextInt(vetor.length) + 1);

            if (vetor[i] % 2 == 0) {
                vetor[i] = x;
                contPar++;
            } else {
                if (vetor[i] % 2 != 0) {
                    vetor[i] = x;
                    contImpar++;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Valor do vetor principal:");
    for (int k = 0; k < vetor.length; k++) {
        System.out.println(vetor[k]);
    }
    System.out.println("Total Par: " + contPar);
    System.out.println("Total Impar: " + contImpar);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/406995/edit) sua pergunta e coloque o código que você possui, mesmo que  possua erros.

Comment: Algumas observações, que não diretamente relacionadas a sua questão porém podem estar atrapalhando: 1) o operador "ou lógico" é composto por duas barras verticais `||`, já o operador "ou de bits" é composto apenas por uma barra vertical `|`, [leia mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34295/64969), 2) o contraponto de `x % 2 == 0` é, necessariamente, `x % 2 != 0`, e isso vale para qualquer expressão de comparação booleana, visto que o operador de "diferente" é o mesmo de "não igual", logo, fazer `if (vetor[i] % 2 == 0) { ... } else if (vetor[i] % 2 != 0) { ...` torna o segundo `if` redundante

Comment: 3) a comparação do `if` está sendo feita sobre o vetor, não sobre `x`; como o valor do vetor que está sendo preenchido, creio que ele não havia sido preenchido anteriormente, é isso mesmo? estaria comparando com valores potencialmente "lixo"? 4) qual o intuito o `while` antes do `for`? como se itera sobre as posições do vetor, se por acaso o vetor tiver pelo menos 9 posições (`2 * 5 - 1`), então garantidamente o `while` não irá disparar, pois terão sido geradas pelo menos 5 números, pares ou ímpares

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta deixa alguns critérios em aberto, então vamos ver algumas abordagens possíveis.

Não foi dito, por exemplo, os limites de valores. Pode ser qualquer número inteiro válido? Em Java, um `int` pode ir de [-2147483648](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE) a [2147483647](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE). O programa pode aceitar qualquer número nesta faixa, pode ser somente positivos, existe um limite mínimo ou máximo?

Assumindo que não existem tais limites, você poderia ter um método que cria um array com uma determinada quantidade de números que obedeçam a um certo critério (no caso, ser par ou ímpar):

```
// ** Atenção: este algoritmo não verifica números repetidos **
public int[] gerarNumeros(int quantidade, boolean par) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int[] numeros = new int[quantidade];
    int i = 0;
    int resto = par ? 0 : 1;
    while (i < quantidade) {
        do {
            numeros[i] = r.nextInt();
        } while (Math.abs(numeros[i]) % 2 != resto);
        // abs() para casos em que o número é negativo, pois -3 % 2 == -1
        i++;
    }

    return numeros;
}
```

Este método recebe a quantidade de números a serem criados, e um `boolean` indicando se quero números pares ou não (se for `true`, gera números pares, se for `false`, gera ímpares).

Depois faço um *loop* para gerar a quantidade de números que preciso. Dentro deste `while` há um `do`/`while` para que gere o número até que ele satisfaça o critério (ser par ou ímpar, de acordo com o `boolean`). Na verificação do resto da divisão por 2, eu uso [`Math.abs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-) para tratar dos casos de números negativos, já que `-3 % 2` resulta em `-1` ([veja](https://ideone.com/ghBGyb)). Usando `abs`, a conta passaria a ser `3 % 2`, resultando em `1`.

O problema do *loop* `do`/`while` é que ele pode rodar várias vezes até encontrar um número que satisfaça o critério. Nesse caso, poderíamos trocá-lo por um `if`:

```
// em vez do do {  ...  } while, use um if
if (Math.abs(numeros[i]) % 2 != resto) {
    numeros[i] += 1;
}
```

Assim, se o critério for par e o número for ímpar (ou vice-versa), basta somar 1. Agora é só gerar os números e juntar tudo em um único array:

```
int[] pares = gerarNumeros(20, true);
int[] impares = gerarNumeros(30, false);
int[] numeros = new int[50];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    numeros[i] = pares[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    numeros[i + 20] = impares[i];
}
```

Ou, se preferir, pode usar [`System.arrayCopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) em vez de dois laços `for`:

```
System.arraycopy(pares, 0, numeros, 0, pares.length);
System.arraycopy(impares, 0, numeros, pares.length, impares.length);
```

Assim, o array `numeros` terá 20 números pares e 30 ímpares, todos gerados aleatoriamente.

Esta solução coloca todos os pares no início (nas primeiras 20 posições), e em seguida os ímpares. Se quiser que eles estejam em ordem aleatória, pode embaralhar o array (veja como mais abaixo). E se quiser limitar os valores dos números, pode usar [`r.nextInt(limiteMaximo)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) em vez de somente `r.nextInt()` (que vai gerar um número entre zero e `limiteMaximo - 1`).

---

#### Não permitir números repetidos

Mas como está indicado nos comentários, esta solução não verifica números repetidos. Neste caso, você teria que usar um [`java.util.Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

```
public Set<Integer> gerarNumerosSemRepeticao(int quantidade, boolean par) {
    Random r = new Random();
    Set<Integer> numeros = new HashSet<>();
    int resto = par ? 0 : 1;
    while (numeros.size() < quantidade) {
        int numero = r.nextInt();
        if (Math.abs(numero) % 2 != resto) {
            numero++;
        }
        if (!numeros.contains(numero)) {
            numeros.add(numero);
        }
    }

    return numeros;
}
```

O `Set` não permite elementos repetidos. O detalhe é que as coleções do Java não permitem tipos primitivos (como o `int`), então tenho que usar um `Set` de [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

Basicamente, se o número gerado não está no `Set`, eu adiciono. Mas se já estiver, não faz nada e continua o *loop*.

A partir daí, basta gerar os números e copiá-los para um array:

```
// gerar os pares
Set<Integer> numeros = gerarNumerosSemRepeticao(20, true);
// gerar os ímpares e já adiciona no Set
numeros.addAll(gerarNumerosSemRepeticao(30, false));

int[] array = new int[numeros.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Integer num : numeros) {
    array[i] = num;
    i++;
}
```

Se estiver usando Java >= 8, pode usar *streams* para gerar o array:

```
int[] array = numeros.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Outra característica do `Set` (além de não permitir números repetidos) é que não há garantia quanto à ordem dos elementos (não necessariamente estarão na mesma ordem em que foram inseridos), então o array resultante provavelmente não terá os pares no início e depois os ímpares.

---

#### Outra abordagem

Outra alternativa é você ter arrays com números predefinidos. Por exemplo, posso gerar dois arrays, com os primeiros 1000 números pares e ímpares:

```
int[] pares = new int[1000];
int[] impares = new int[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    pares[i] = 2 * i;
    impares[i] = pares[i] + 1;
}
```

No caso, eu tenho os números pares entre zero e 1998, e os ímpares entre 1 e 1999.

Agora basta embaralhar estes arrays e pegar os primeiros N elementos de cada um. Para embaralhar, você pode usar o [algoritmo de embaralhamento de Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
public void embaralha(int arr[]) {
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int j = r.nextInt(i + 1);

        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Em seguida, embaralhe os arrays de pares e ímpares, e pegue a quantidade que você precisa de cada um:

```
embaralha(pares);
embaralha(impares);

int[] numeros = new int[50];
// copia somente 20 pares
System.arraycopy(pares, 0, numeros, 0, 20);
// copia somente 30 ímpares
System.arraycopy(impares, 0, numeros, 20, 30);
```

Esta solução, assim como a anterior, também coloca todos os pares no início, e em seguida os ímpares. Mas você poderia embaralhar o resultado usando `embaralha(numeros)`, se quiser (a pergunta não deixa claro a ordem em que os números devem estar).